# I cannot determine what video driver I am using

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have an AMD RX 5700 XT Graphics card and I don't know what driver is being used. When I looked online, people said to do `lshw -c video` and that the driver is supposed to be on the configuration line.

But `sudo lshw -c video` outputs this:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 10
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd7ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

But it is not there. Does this mean that there is no driver installed?

Comment: Go to `update-manager` and the click `Settings...`. Select `Additional Drivers` and try to find an appropriate driver for your graphics card. (Note: I do not have the same card as you, so I cannot guide you further.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's *no* driver used. The `*-display` section is marked as `UNCLAIMED`, in short meaning "I couldn't find a fitting driver for this". There can be multiple `*-display` sections, for example if the machine has multiple graphic cards. Maybe you're looking at the wrong one?

Comment: I only have one graphics card, I tried installing amd driver from amd website but that gives me error, I'm on 19.10 but the website says that the drivers are for 18.04 so maybe that's it

Comment: @oali24 I'm no expert on graphic cards, but a quick search shows that "Navi 10" is probably a very new card. There's the chance that Ubuntu, or Linux in general, doesn't support it yet. Maybe you've fallen back to a integrated graphics system of your mainboard, or something.

Comment: Linux 5.3+  (and  Mesa 19.2+) is required for a Navi 10. And indeed looks like it falls back to the integrated Intel.

Comment: and if feeling adventorous: here are the binaries: https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/navi10/